# Using Case When Statement For Updating from Two Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, plsqldeveloper

Is it possible to update a column of a table from two optional tables, in Oracle. I mean, there are 2 tables whose columns are exactly same and, according to input Id, I want to update related table.
For eg.

```
UPDATE CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT A.ID FROM Table_A A 
    WHERE  A.ID = 'B1'
    )
    THEN
      Table_A A 
      SET A.Status = '0'
      WHERE A.ID = 'B1'
    ELSE
      Table_B B
      SET B.Status = '0'
      WHERE B.ID = 'B1'
```

Where Table_A and Table_B has exactly same columns with different records.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEGIN
  UPDATE Table_A A SET STATUS = '0' WHERE A.ID = #ID#;
    if sql%notfound then
    UPDATE Table_B B SET STATUS = '0' WHERE B.ID = #ID#;
    END IF;
END;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with a single statment, but you could achieve it using PL/SQL:

```
declare
VarCount number;

begin

SELECT  COUNT(*)
INTO    VarCount
FROM    Table_A
WHERE   ID = 'B1';

IF  VarCount > 1  THEN
    UPDATE  Table_A
    SET     Status = '0'
    WHERE   ID = 'B1';
ELSE
    UPDATE  Table_B
    SET     Status = '0'
    WHERE   ID = 'B1';
END IF;
```

end;

Comment: Thank you Weenoid, I guess it is possible in T-Sql but not in PL/SQL.
It throws ORA-00900 when I try.

Comment: Sorry i'm not that familiar with Oracle, please see my updated example (I can't test it myself i'm afraid)

Comment: Thanks again my friend, but again it did not work. I have used T-SQL for a long time, and I know it works in SQL Developer. But I cannot run it in Oracle...

Comment: @weenoid It doesn't work because on PL/SQL you end statements with ';' and ifs are written 'if condition then' plus you need to add an 'end if'

Comment: @weenoid check out sqlfiddle.com - you can test your queries against  Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, Postgres, etc.

Comment: @weenoid there were some more changes needed so I took the liberty of editing myself. You'll be able to see them when approved :)

Comment: @ChadHenderson. Thanks for the link. I realise i'm probably doing more harm than good guessing at syntax, but i'm at work and i'm bored :p.

Comment: Almost complete.. There needs to be a BEGIN ... END; around the SELECT to END IF; block and you need to add semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder why you would want this functionality. All I can think of is that you have a lot of data, and decided to split it by using 1 "archive" table and 1 "active" table.

In that case, you could simply always update both tables. If the id doesn't exist, nothing will be updated. It might be just as fast as first selecting by id from table a, and then updating either a or b.
You could also use a pl/sql block for better performance. (It will only execute a second statement when necessary)

```
create or replace procedure update_table(p_id in table_a.id%type)
as
begin
    update table_a
    set    status = 0
    where  id = p_id;

    -- only update table_b if table_a didn't update anything
    if sql%rowcount == 0 then
        update table_b
        set    status = 0
        where  id = p_id;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I have a main and a log table with huge amount of data. So I need this.